# Why did Vincent risk his chance of going to space by giving his true urine sample to Dr. Lamar in the last scene?

Tags: gattaca

In Gattaca (1997), in the last scene, Vincent came to the test room and met Dr. Lamar for his final test before boarding the spaceship. I understand that Dr. Lamar had known Vincent's true identity from the beginning, but he chose to ignore it because he felt a connection between his son and Vincent. However, what I don't understand is why Vincent gave Dr. Lamar his true urine sample right before boarding when he didn't know that Dr. Lamar was aware of his true identity. Shouldn't he have given his false identity and passed the test as he did on other normal days?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

No one, including Lamar, knew there was a final test — as he would have warned Vincent. When Vincent asks him, he shrugs "*New policy*"

> *Shouldn't he have given his false identity and passed the test as he did on other normal days?*

He had no choice. It was a surprise test, even for Dr Lamar, who also knew what problem that posed for Vincent.

From an [early draft of the script](https://thescriptlab.com/wp-content/uploads/scripts/Gattaca-Screenplay.pdf):

> INT.  GATTACA - DEPARTURE LOUNGE.  NIGHT.
>
> JEROME enters a large holding area along with his other eleven CREW
> MEMBERS.
>
> Jerome's heart sinks as he recognizes LAMAR, greeting the crew for one
> final **unexpected** substance test.  His colleagues groan good-naturedly
> but it is clearly far more than an inconvenience to Jerome.  He looks
> towards the door he has just entered but there is no way back.  One by
> one the crew are ushered behind a screen.  Before he can think of a
> way out, it is Jerome's turn.  He enters the cubicle.
>
> JEROME: (as he takes the plastic cup from Lamar) What's this, Lamar?
>
> LAMAR: **New policy**.
>
> From behind, we see Jerome unzip his fly.  However for once Jerome
> does not urinate on cue - unused to operating his own equipment in
> front of the physician.
>
> LAMAR: (intrigued by the out-of-character discharge) Flight got you
> nervous?
>
> JEROME: There's a problem, Lamar.
>
> LAMAR: (apparently not listening) Did I ever tell you about my son,
> Jerome?  He's a big fan of yours.  He wants to apply here.
>
> **Jerome realizes he has no choice.  Resigned to his fate, he begins to
> fill the cup.**

Comment: @blobbymcblobby um...ok, so that was a suprise test for all included Dr. Lamar. But in the movie, when the computer showed the true identity of him, why did Vincent look so confident? He even smiled at Dr. Lamar when both look at his true identiy. I thought he should have been worried because all his years of effort would have been gone in vain at that moment.

Comment: Because, as written in the script and in the movie, it was a point of no return. He was about to blow it all with a defiant speech too, when Lamar cut him off and gave him a pass. Only him and Lamar saw the true ID turn up before Lamar fixed it again

Comment: Its not so much confidence, more, hell, this is it, i'm screwed, so I'll smile, know i did my best and make a defiant speech, to perhaps the only guy who might understand, before i am taken away, torn asunder from my hard worked for dream...!